# How move a rectangle with arrow keys while clearing the canvas in between every re-draw

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

    <head>

        <title></title>

        <style>

            canvas {
                border: 1px solid black;
                width: 1200px;
                height: 600px;
            }

        </style>

    </head>

    <body>

        <script>
            var z = document.createElement("CANVAS");
            var ctx = z.getContext("2d");

            var x = 20;
            var y = 20;

            ctx.fillRect(x, y, 5, 5);
            ctx.stroke();
            document.body.appendChild(z);

            document.onkeydown = checkKey;

            function checkKey(e) {


                e = e || window.event;

                if (e.keyCode == '38') {
                    y--;
                    ctx.fillRect(x, y, 5, 5);

                }
                else if (e.keyCode == '40') {
                    // down arrow
                    ctx.fillRect(x, y, 5, 5);

                }
                else if (e.keyCode == '37') {
                    // left arrow
                    x--;
                    ctx.fillRect(x, y, 5, 5);

                }
                else if (e.keyCode == '39') {
                    // right arrow
                    x++;
                    ctx.fillRect(x, y, 5, 5);

                }

            }

        </script>


    </body>

</html>
```

Every time I try to clear the canvas with: ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 1200, 600); or ctx.clearCanvas(); nothing happens. The rectangle doesnt even move. I put this between the x++; and the ctx.fillRect();. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the corrected code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

    <head>

        <title></title>

        <style>

            canvas {
                border: 1px solid black;
                width: 1200px;
                height: 600px;
            }

        </style>

    </head>

    <body>

        <script>
            var z = document.createElement("CANVAS");
            var ctx = z.getContext("2d");

            var x = 20;
            var y = 20;

            ctx.fillRect(x, y, 5, 5);
            ctx.stroke();
            document.body.appendChild(z);

            document.onkeydown = checkKey;
          function clear() {
            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, z.width, z.height);
          }

            function checkKey(e) {

e.preventDefault();
                e = e || window.event;

                if (e.keyCode == '38') {
                    y--; clear();
                    ctx.fillRect(x, y, 5, 5);

                }
                if (e.keyCode == '40') {
                    // down arrow
                    y++;clear();
                    ctx.fillRect(x, y, 5, 5);

                }
                if (e.keyCode == '37') {
                    // left arrow
                  clear();
                    x--;
                    ctx.fillRect(x, y, 5, 5);

                }
                if (e.keyCode == '39') {
                    // right arrow
                  clear();
                    x++;
                    ctx.fillRect(x, y, 5, 5);

                }

            }

        </script>


    </body>

</html>
</body>
</html>
```

To clear the whole canvas, you need this:

```
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, z.width, z.height);
```

You put it between the `x++` and `ctx.fillRect()`.

I also see another error in your code:

> When you handle the down arrow key event, you don't use `y++` so the rectangle don't move down. I corrected this for you.
>   Error 2: You don't use `e.preventDefault` so every time I move the rectangle, the window scroll too (if it is too small).